# Using react router, can't extract parameters even though they are there (using typescript)

Tags: typescript, react-router

I'm trying to switch over an old project to use react and react-router. I'm also new to typescript, which is used for the project, so any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

That route is defined like this:

```
<Route
   path="/deployments/:somePrefix/:someId"
   component={SomeDetailPage}/>
```

However, in SomeDetailPage, when I try to access the parameters so I can call a function on them (`(this.props.match.params.somePrefix`, or `this.proper.match.params.someId)`) , I get this error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] src/public/components/some-detail-page.tsx:25:97
    Property 'somePrefix' does not exist on type '{}'

ERROR in [at-loader] src/public/components/some-detail-page.tsx:25:97
    Property 'someId' does not exist on type '{}'
```

However, I know that those params exist, because when I try to test and put the params as part of a div (just random testing), the div doesn't load and I get this error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {somePrefix, someId})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you typing the Props for `SomeDetailPage`?

You'll want to make sure that you are correctly adding in the `RouteComponentProps` from `react-router-dom`.

For instance, you will need something along the lines of

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

// Define what your match should look like
interface SomeDetailPageMatch {
    somePrefix: string;
    someId: string;
}

interface SomeDetailPagePropsFromParent {
    // Your custom props here
}

type SomeDetailPageProps = SomeDetailPagePropsFromParent &
    RouteComponentProps<SomeDetailPageMatch>; // Provide your match as generic

class SomeDetailPage extends React.Component<SomeDetailPageProps> {

...
```

Then it should understand that `this.props.match.params.someId` and `this.props.match.params.somePrefix` exist.